# Retrieve json data to display in datatable, serverside

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

Basically I don't know how to make the connections, I am lost in all the information I have found and after initializing the dataTable with `data`-json format, I found that if I filter the data by date, I have an error (DataTables warning: table id={id} - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.), because, as in documentation : *DataTables does not allow initialisation options to be altered at any time other than at initialisation time*, so I must retrieve data by ajax and here I don't know how to proceed.

HTML:

```html
<table class="table table-borderless" style="overflow: scroll" width="100%" id="topAlarmsDeviceLine">
</table>
```

JS:

```
this.tableDevicesbyAlarmsTime = function (data) {
        let tableModel = [
            {
                targets: 0,
                data: 'Denumire',
            },
            {
                data: 'processor',
                targets: 1,
                render: function(data, type, row) {
                    if (type === 'display' && data > 59) {
                        return Math.round(data / 60) + 'h' + "<span class='border border-dark-subtle border-2 border-start-0' style='background-color: #F0AD4E; width:10px; height:10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle;'></span>";
                    } else if(type === 'display' && 0 < data && data < 60) {
                        return data + 'm' + "<span class='border border-dark-subtle border-2 border-start-0' style='background-color: #F0AD4E; width:10px; height:10px; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle;'></span>";
                    } else {
                        return "";
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        ];
        console.log(data);
        $('#topAlarmsDeviceLine').DataTable({
            serverSide: true,
            //data: data,
            //retrieve: true,
            searching: false,
            ordering: false,
            paging: false,
            language: {
                info: "",
                zeroRecords: "",
            },
            columnDefs: tableModel,
            ajax: //?,
        });
    };

this.refreshDashboardData = function () {
        $.get(getUrl('inventoree/endpoint_dashboard_data'), {
                'start': this.getStartDate(),
                'end': this.getEndDate(),
            },
            'json')
            .done(function (data) {
                this.refreshDashboard(data);
            }.bind(this));
    };
this.refreshDashboard = function (data) {
        this.topAlarmsChart(data.alarms_number);
        this.topAlarmsDevice(data.top_alarms);
        this.tableDevicesbyAlarmsTime(data.top_alarms);
       
    };
```

controller:

```
public function endpoint_dashboard_data()
    {
        $this->load->model('inventoree/endpoint_dashboard');

        $options['from'] = $this->input->get('start');
        $options['to'] = $this->input->get('end');

        $data = [
            ...
            'top_alarms'      => $this->endpoint_dashboard->getAlarmNumberByDevice($options),
            
        ];
        $this->sendJsonOutput($data);
    }
```

I am not sure if I must change the table model aswell...instead of 'render' to be 'data' and I can use the 'refreshDashboard' method in ajax somehow...or should I just do something like:

```
ajax: {
    url: getUrl('inventoree/endpoint_dashboard_data'),
    data: function (d) {
        d.start = this.getStartDate();
        d.end = this.getEndDate();
    }.bind(this),
    // Set the type of request to GET
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
}
```

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: You should only use one Ajax call - the one in the DataTable definition. That is automatically fired whenever the user performs a sort, filter, or paging action _on the DataTable_. This should greatly simplify your JavaScript code - which seems overly complicated, right now.

Comment: If you have _external_ HTML fields which are not in the DataTable (e.g. for filtering by start date and end date) then your use of the `data` function is the right approach. You haven't shown what these fields are, so this is a guess: You also need to respond to a user changing these filter values (which are not part of the DataTable???) - and therefore you can use [`ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) for that.

Comment: yes,sry for omitting that, the filters are not part of DataTable, because beside the table I also have some charts made with other library and the filter must be applied on every chart and my table. So...I don't need to initialize ajax.data?

Comment: "_so I don't need to initialize ajax.data?_" - You don't need to _re-initialize_ it - if that's what you mean. (And you don't need to `bind()` it to anything, either.)

Comment: If I don't use ` bind() `, I have error that `this` is undefined, and after I have error: `Uncaught TypeError: s is undefined`.... .

Comment: That comes back to my first comment, about the overly complicated JS code. Can you provide a [mre]? Something we can copy, paste and run for ourselves - including a sample of representative data?

Comment: Is a little complicated...I don't know how to reproduce this in a minimal way...in the code I provided I didn't specified that refreshDashboard function is called on refresh after date range was changed. Also if I console.log(data), it returns an array of objects: [
  { Denumire: 'CP', processor: 25 },
  { Denumire: 'KJ', processor: 30 }
];, in controller is returned in JSON format.

Comment: and I taught I can do just ajax: data, given that refreshDashboardData function has the url and everything, and the data is passed through refreshDashboard, this.topAlarmsDevice(data.top_alarms) and to my function which contains the datatable...

Comment: OK thank you. But there are no dates in that sample, and I think dates are important to the logic. There is no HTML, also, showing how dates are entered/selected by the user... and so on. Add the new info to the question (where you can format it properly).

Comment: I think there is going to be too much info missing for me to be able to help you with confidence, unfortunately. I am sorry about that.